# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 inserting into the database using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to insert into the database using codeigniter. On filling the form to click submit I get error during the process.
This is a snippet of the method in the model class

```
function success_shop()
    {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO table VALUES('$name')");
    }
```

in the controller code I have this snippet

```
function success_shop(){
       $this->load->model('pro_memo_model');
       $this->pro_memo_model->success_shop();
       $this->load->view('preview_general_acc');//loading success view

   }
```

On entering data in the form to click submit I get this error

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1136

Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Please what could be wrong?

Comment: ` $this->db->query("INSERT INTO table(name) VALUES('$name')");`

Comment: $this->db->query("INSERT INTO table VALUES('$name')"); should be $this->db->query("INSERT INTO table set name='$name'"); if name is the column you are updating

Comment: where is the typo

Comment: if you wanna insert single data in your table you need to mention the filed name  like `insert into tbl_name(filed1,filed2...) values (filed1value,filed2value,...)` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,..) VALUES('val1','val2',..);
```

Try above code.

Hope this will helps.

Comment: $this->db->query("INSERT INTO table ('name') VALUES('$name')");

Comment: is that okay. name is a field in the table

Comment: `INSERT INTO table (\`NAME\`) VALUES ('$name');` Try this one.

Comment: Yes it is ok @parker

Comment: this worked for me 
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES('$name')");

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in codeigniter

```
$data['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$this->db->insert('table', $data);
```